# Bundling React components into a parent component

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I'm developing a custom WordPress block with a block editor panel that needs to dynamically hide and show some components based on the state of other components. The way I'm managing this at present is by having multiple different return clauses under nested conditionals that pivot off of the state set by the block controls. See some trimmed example code below (from the edit.js file at the bottom of the "Edit" function):

```js
if (blockMode === 'group') {
    if (directoryLinkMode === 'profileBlock') {
        return (
            <>
                <InspectorControls>
                    {   
                        <Panel>
                            <PanelBody>
                                
                                <RadioControl
                                    label="Block mode"
                                    selected={blockMode}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: 'Group selection', value: 'group'},
                                        {label: 'Individual selection', value: 'individual'},
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(val) => updateBlockMode(val)}
                                />

                                <RadioControl
                                    label="Directory link mode"
                                    selected={directoryLinkMode}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: 'CAES directory', value: 'CAES'},
                                        {label: 'Extension directory', value: 'extension'},
                                        {label: 'Profile block', value: 'profileBlock'},
                                        {label: 'None', value: 'none'},
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(val) => updateDirectoryLinkMode(val)}
                                />

                                <TextControl
                                    label="Personnel block URL"
                                    value={personnelBlockURL}
                                    onChange={(val) => updatePersonnelBlockURL(val)}
                                />

                                <SelectControl
                                    label="Department"
                                    options = {
                                        deptsList
                                    }
                                    // value={attributes.dept_ID}
                                    value={selectedDept}
                                    // onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ dept_ID: Number(val) })}
                                    onChange={(val) => updateSelectedDept(val)}
                                />

                                {/* <SelectControl
                                    label="Personnel"
                                    options = {
                                        personnelList
                                    }
                                    value={attributes.personnel_ID}
                                    onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ personnel_ID: Number(val) })}
                                /> */}

                                <FormTokenField
                                    label="Omit selected personnel (max 6)"
                                    value={ omittedPersonnel }
                                    suggestions={ personnelNameList }
                                    onChange={ ( tokens ) => updateOmittedPersonnel( tokens ) }
                                />

                            </PanelBody>
                        </Panel>
                    }
                </InspectorControls>

                <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
                    <ServerSideRender 
                        block="uga-caes/personnel"
                        attributes = {attributes}
                    />
                </div>
            </>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                <InspectorControls>
                    {   
                        <Panel>
                            <PanelBody>
                                
                                <RadioControl
                                    label="Block mode"
                                    selected={blockMode}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: 'Group selection', value: 'group'},
                                        {label: 'Individual selection', value: 'individual'},
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(val) => updateBlockMode(val)}
                                />

                                <RadioControl
                                    label="Directory link mode"
                                    selected={directoryLinkMode}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: 'CAES directory', value: 'CAES'},
                                        {label: 'Extension directory', value: 'extension'},
                                        {label: 'Profile block', value: 'profileBlock'},
                                        {label: 'None', value: 'none'},
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(val) => updateDirectoryLinkMode(val)}
                                />

                                <SelectControl
                                    label="Department"
                                    options = {
                                        deptsList
                                    }
                                    // value={attributes.dept_ID}
                                    value={selectedDept}
                                    // onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ dept_ID: Number(val) })}
                                    onChange={(val) => updateSelectedDept(val)}
                                />

                                {/* <SelectControl
                                    label="Personnel"
                                    options = {
                                        personnelList
                                    }
                                    value={attributes.personnel_ID}
                                    onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ personnel_ID: Number(val) })}
                                /> */}

                                <FormTokenField
                                    label="Omit selected personnel (max 6)"
                                    value={ omittedPersonnel }
                                    suggestions={ personnelNameList }
                                    onChange={ ( tokens ) => updateOmittedPersonnel( tokens ) }
                                />

                            </PanelBody>
                        </Panel>
                    }
                </InspectorControls>

                <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
                    <ServerSideRender 
                        block="uga-caes/personnel"
                        attributes = {attributes}
                    />
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
} else {
    if (directoryLinkMode === 'profileBlock') {
        return (
            <>
                <InspectorControls>
                    {   
                        <Panel>
                            <PanelBody>

                                <RadioControl
                                    label="Block mode"
                                    selected={blockMode}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: 'Group selection', value: 'group'},
                                        {label: 'Individual selection', value: 'individual'},
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(val) => updateBlockMode(val)}
                                />

                                <RadioControl
                                    label="Directory link mode"
                                    selected={directoryLinkMode}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: 'CAES directory', value: 'CAES'},
                                        {label: 'Extension directory', value: 'extension'},
                                        {label: 'Profile block', value: 'profileBlock'},
                                        {label: 'None', value: 'none'},
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(val) => updateDirectoryLinkMode(val)}
                                />

                                <TextControl
                                    label="Personnel block URL"
                                    value={personnelBlockURL}
                                    onChange={(val) => updatePersonnelBlockURL(val)}
                                />

                                <FormTokenField
                                    label="Display selected personnel (max 6)"
                                    value={ selectedPersonnelNames }
                                    suggestions={ personnelNameList }
                                    onChange={ ( tokens ) => updateSelectedPersonnelNames( tokens ) }
                                />
                                
                            </PanelBody>
                        </Panel>
                    }
                </InspectorControls>

                <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
                    <ServerSideRender 
                        block="uga-caes/personnel"
                        attributes = {attributes}
                    />
                </div>
            </>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                <InspectorControls>
                    {   
                        <Panel>
                            <PanelBody>

                                <RadioControl
                                    label="Block mode"
                                    selected={blockMode}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: 'Group selection', value: 'group'},
                                        {label: 'Individual selection', value: 'individual'},
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(val) => updateBlockMode(val)}
                                />

                                <RadioControl
                                    label="Directory link mode"
                                    selected={directoryLinkMode}
                                    options={[
                                        {label: 'CAES directory', value: 'CAES'},
                                        {label: 'Extension directory', value: 'extension'},
                                        {label: 'Profile block', value: 'profileBlock'},
                                        {label: 'None', value: 'none'},
                                    ]}
                                    onChange={(val) => updateDirectoryLinkMode(val)}
                                />

                                <FormTokenField
                                    label="Display selected personnel (max 6)"
                                    value={ selectedPersonnelNames }
                                    suggestions={ personnelNameList }
                                    onChange={ ( tokens ) => updateSelectedPersonnelNames( tokens ) }
                                />
                                    
                            </PanelBody>
                        </Panel>
                    }
                </InspectorControls>

                <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
                    <ServerSideRender 
                        block="uga-caes/personnel"
                        attributes = {attributes}
                    />
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Obviously this is causing a lot of bloat and redundancy (it's actually much worse than what's shown here).

Is it possible to preassemble the React components, perhaps as child components inside of a custom-defined parent component, so that I can use the conditional logic during the assembly of a master component to be returned and then have only a single return statement? What would this look like? An example with just two child components and one conditional would suffice.